# How to run for-loops for parts of data frame at the time?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, subset

An R newbie here! I have a data frame where there are several measurements for the same ID. Here's a simplified example of it.

```
id<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
x<-as.numeric(c(1:9))
y<-c(2,4,1,5,7,3,9,6,8)
z<-rep("text",9)
cal<-0
df<- data.frame(id, x, y,z,cal)
```

I would like to run a following loop through the measurements for each ID separately because I want to plot the cal values separately for the different IDs.

```
for (j in 2:length(df$x))
  {if (df$x[j]>=df$y[j]) {df$cal[j]<-df$x[j]+df$y[j-1]
  }else{
     df$cal[j]<- df$x[j]-df$y[j-1]
    }
  }
```

So basically I'd like that the loop works through the first ID, before jumping to second and then third and so on. The expected outcome would be the following data frame (the 0s are a coincidence) :

```
> df
  id x y    z cal
1  1 1 2 text   0
2  1 2 4 text   0
3  1 3 1 text   7
-----------------
4  2 4 5 text   0
5  2 5 7 text   0
6  2 6 3 text   13
-----------------
7  3 7 9 text   0
8  3 8 6 text   17
9  3 9 8 text   15
```

As I did not want to create subset of data frames for each ID, I tried using a for-loop for the IDs as well.

```
for (i in 1:3)
{if (df$id==i) {
  for (j in 2:length(df$x))
  {if (df$x[j]>=df$y[j]) {df$cal[j]<-df$x[j]+df$y[j-1]
  }else{
     df$cal[j]<- df$x[j]-df$y[j-1]
    }
  }
}
}
```

However, this gave the following warning: `1: In if (df$id == i) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

So, I know now that this is because I'm trying to compare a vector into another vector that is supposed to give "TRUE" or "FALSE". However, comparing the IDs of the different rows does not help either, because then I need to manually always change the ID value, e.g. `for (i in 1:length(which(df$id==1)))`.

I've been trying to figure out other ways how to do this, but haven't found an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you add a sample of your expected output?

Comment: @NelsonGon I added the type of data frame I expected to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) # this loads several packages that will help you.

df %>% # now you take your df
    mutate(cal = if_else(x >= y # and calculate the column cal
                         , x + lag(y) # if x >= y then calculate this
                         , x - lag(y))) # else calculate this

  id x y    z cal
1  1 1 2 text  NA
2  1 2 4 text   0
3  1 3 1 text   7
4  2 4 5 text   3
5  2 5 7 text   0
6  2 6 3 text  13
7  3 7 9 text   4
8  3 8 6 text  17
9  3 9 8 text  15
```

You don't need the loop. R is vectorized. `lag()` creates a vector that is "shifted" by one element.

It's unclear what the second part of the question is about, but could it be that you are looking for this?

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(cal = if_else(x >= y
                         , x + lag(y)
                         , x - lag(y)))

    id     x     y z       cal
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
    1     1     1     2 text     NA
    2     1     2     4 text      0
    3     1     3     1 text      7
    4     2     4     5 text     NA
    5     2     5     7 text      0
    6     2     6     3 text     13
    7     3     7     9 text     NA
    8     3     8     6 text     17
    9     3     9     8 text     15
```

Comment: Thank you @Georgery! This looks much more straigthforward way to do it. Would it also work if I want to point x as a new cal if x >y and keep the old cal if x<y? E.g. `cal= if_else(x >= y, x, lag(cal))`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, but in `mutate()` you can calculate this new version as well. You can also assign it to another variable: `mutate(cal2 = if_else(x >= y, x, lag(cal))`

Comment: Great, that's what I meant. Thank you!